# Access axes object in seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Most seaborn plotting functions (e.g. `seaborn.barplot`, `seaborn.regplot`) return a `matplotlib.pyplot.axes` when called, so that you can use this object to further customize the plot as you see fit.

However, I wanted to create an [`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html), which doesn't return the axes object. After digging through the documentation of both `seaborn.lmplot` and [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) (which `lmplot` uses in it's backend), I found **no** way of accessing the underlying `axes` objects. Moreover, while most other seaborn functions allow you to pass your own `axes` as a parameter on which they will draw the plot on, `lmplot` **doesn't**.

One thing I thought of is using `plt.gca()`, but that only returns the **last** `axes` object of the grid.

Is there any way of accessing the `axes` objects in `seaborn.lmplot` or `seaborn.FacetGrid`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can access the `matplotlib.pyplot.axes` object like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
lm = sns.lmplot(...)  # draw a grid of plots
ax = lm.axes  # access a grid of 'axes' objects
```

Here, `ax` is an array containing **all** axes objects in the subplot. You can access each one like this:

```
ax.shape  # see the shape of the array containing the 'axes' objects
ax[0, 0]  # the top-left (first) subplot 
ax[i, j]  # the subplot on the i-th row of the j-th column
```

If there is only one subplot you can either access it as I showed above (with `ax[0, 0]`) or as you said in your question through (`plt.gca()`)

Comment: Wow, it was that easy... I feel stupid now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! :)